# SQL query to findout original tables from a database in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to findout original tablenames and their related backup tables from information schema but seeing some different results.below is the query i am using but it is not giving expected results. your help is much appriciated.

we have tables in information schema like below

| table_names |
| --- |
| emp |
| em_copy |
| emp_test |
| emp_0101bkp |
| emp_bkp |

output:

| original_table | backuptable |
| --- | --- |
| emp | emp_bkp |
| emp | emp_copy |
| emp | emp_0101bkp |
| emp | emp_test |

below query i am using but i am missing `emp_0101bkp` in the output.

**Query that i am using:**

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,ORIGINALTABLE,BACKUPTABLE,CREATED 
FROM (
   SELECT
   TABLE_SCHEMA,
   REGEXP_REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, '_BKP.*','') AS OriginalTable,
   TABLE_NAME AS BackupTable,
   CREATED
   FROM EDW_LS.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('schema1','schema2')
   AND (TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_BKP' OR 
        TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_%BKP_%')

--ORDER BY ORIGINALTABLE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, '_COPY.*','') AS OriginalTable,
    TABLE_NAME AS BackupTable,CREATED
    FROM EDW_LS.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('schema1','schema2')
    AND (TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_COPY' 
         OR TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_%COPY_%')

--order by TABLE_SCHEMA,ORIGINALTABLE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
     REGEXP_REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, '_TEST.*','') AS OriginalTable,
    TABLE_NAME AS BackupTable,CREATED
    FROM EDW_LS.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('schema1','schema2')
    AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_TEST'
)
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ORIGINALTABLE ORDER BY CREATED DESC)>2
```

Comment: Hi - please format your SQL so it’s readable. There are plenty of websites that will format it for you if you need them

Comment: Are you using clones for backup tables?

Comment: No, I am removing backup tables, meaing we are keeping latest 3 versions of backups and dropping which are having more than 3 versions of backups.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, directly, but may I suggest that you start to leverage clones for your backup strategies.  Not only do they save storage space, but they also require no compute to create.  The other added benefit is that you could get the information you're looking for in this post by simply querying the `TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS` in account_usage, since that view tracks the relationships of clones to the originating table.

Comment: Thanks Mike, We are using cloning only for backups, now we need to delete/drop these cloned tables by keeping latest 3 versions and drop rest of the versions.